# Unable to deserialize Json array to model object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get info from constant contact web api through url and parsing the result from json array to model object. But the model object is always null. The fetched information is successfully stored in variable but never gets converted to object. Below is what i have done!

**class.css**

```
 public class CCModel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Address> addresses { get; set; }
        public List<List> lists { get; set; }
        public string cell_phone { get; set; }
        public string company_name { get; set; }
        public bool confirmed { get; set; }
        public List<EmailAddress> email_addresses { get; set; }
        public string fax { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string home_phone { get; set; }
        public string job_title { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string middle_name { get; set; }
        public string prefix_name { get; set; }
        public string work_phone { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
        public string source_details { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public List<CustomFields> custom_fields { get; set; }
        public string modified_date { get; set; }
        public List<Notes> notes { get; set; }


    }
```

**Convert Section**

```
  var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                                JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(a.ToString());
                                lstModel = new CCModel();
                                lstModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CCModel>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); // here it is always null
```

and the var a holds this

```
"results": [
    {
      "id": "1154958965",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "fax": "",
      "addresses": [],
      "notes": [],
      "confirmed": false,
      "lists": [
        {
          "id": "1597641299",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      ],
      "source": "Site Owner",
      "email_addresses": [
        {
          "id": "55071710-5db2-11e8-bced-d4ae5275509e",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "confirm_status": "NO_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED",
          "opt_in_source": "ACTION_BY_OWNER",
          "opt_in_date": "2018-05-22T11:21:54Z",
          "email_address": "XXX"
        }
      ],
      "prefix_name": "",
      "first_name": "XXX",
      "middle_name": "",
      "last_name": "XXX",
      "job_title": "Developer",
      "company_name": "Codeit",
      "home_phone": "",
      "work_phone": "",
      "cell_phone": "",
      "custom_fields": [],
      "created_date": "2018-05-22T11:21:54Z",
      "modified_date": "2018-05-23T11:02:09Z",
      "source_details": ""
    }
  ]
```

**Note:** Remember there is only one result fetched, so not parsing it into list of object model

Comment: I'm pretty confident that you directly accessing the result of the async operation is causing the problem. Implement the async await pattern instead of directly accessing the result

Comment: Most probably your mapping of json to c# object is wrong. Copy your json result and convert it to c# classes by goung to visual studio > Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as classes. And then try running it.

Comment: Are you referring to configureawait(false)?

Comment: Your json consists of a property, "results", holding an array of objects, you're going to have to match up your objects to this structure. Additionally, you're lacking the outer object brackes of the object that has this property. You need to have valid json before you can parse it.

Comment: Additionally, you're reading the content twice, are you sure that is even possible? Try caching the result of reading the json into a string once and reuse twice.

Comment: And "it is always null", there are multiple things in that line that can end up as null, which one is it? If it is the "lstModel" variable, then this is because your json does not match your object.

Comment: Yes it is lstModel which is always null.

Comment: All the properties in the lstModel are having same name matching with the result of json array. Does it have anything do with the results tag in the json array?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned it does. Your JSON doesn’t match the data structure you’re trying to deserialize it into. Also there’s no need to create a CCModel object and then immediately assign the result of deserialization to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                                JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(a.ToString());
                                lstModel = new CCModel();
                                lstModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CCModel>(a); <-------------
```

Once you have a ,then why do you need to get the same response again. Try this. "var a" is already in memory.